# Ant only copy the file not directories

Tags: ant

I have structure like

```
      dir--
           dir1--
                fil1.pro
                file.xml
           dir2--
                file.pro
```

and more

Form that i just want to copy only .pro files not including dir1 and dir2 and so on. I tried this but its copied directories too.

```
<target name="properties-core">
    <mkdir dir="${dir.dist.properties}"/>
    <copy todir="${dir.dist.properties}">
                <fileset dir="${dir.plugin.defs}"> --- it has many folders inside form those folders i just want to copy .pro files
                    <include name="**/*.properties" />
                    <type type="file" />
                </fileset>
            </copy> 
</target>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flatten="true"` in the `copy` task to ignore the directory structure of the source files. Also the pattern should be `**/*.pro` not `**/*.properties` (seems like a typo in your question).

```
<target name="properties-core">
    <mkdir dir="${dir.dist.properties}"/>
    <copy todir="${dir.dist.properties}" flatten="true" >
        <fileset dir="${dir.plugin.defs}">
            <include name="**/*.pro" />
        </fileset>
    </copy> 
</target>
```